# How can I create reusable navigation menu in ASP MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following navigation html/code now duplicated across several Views:

```cs
<ul class="topNav">
    <li class="selected">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Dashboard", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Stats", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Answers", "Answers", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Contacts", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") })</li>
</ul>
```

Of course in each View the `class="selected"` of the `li` is changed. Is there an easy way to place this block of code in a Partial View or Layout View?

Also, must I really use `ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id")` to get to the `id` parameter of the controller or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to handle that.

1. If you want a really reusable (Application independ solution) you should create a HtmlHelper Method
   [Creating Custom HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)
2. If you need it just in your Application consider doing something like that.

   ```
   public static class ControllerHelper
   {
   /// <summary>
   /// Checks the current action via RouteData
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="helper">The HtmlHelper object to extend</param>
   /// <param name="actionName">The Action</param>
   /// <param name="controllerName">The Controller</param>
   /// <returns>Boolean</returns>
   public static bool IsCurrentAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName, string controllerName)
   {
       string currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
       string currentActionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

       if (currentControllerName.Equals(controllerName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && currentActionName.Equals(actionName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
           return true;

       return false;

   }
   }


   <ul class="topNav">
     <li @if(Html.IsCurrentAction("DashBoard", "DashBoard")) { <text>class="selected"</text> }>@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Dashboard", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") })</li>
     <li>@if(Html.IsCurrentAction("Stats", "Stats")) { <text>class="selected"</text> }>@Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Stats", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") })</li>

   // ....
   </ul>
   ```

**Please tell me if you want to implement the first approach, i will provide more help**

**hope this helps**

Comment: I read through the link you provided or Creating Custom HTML Helpers. Isn't that actually what you are doing in #2? After all, #2 it is an Extension Method to HtmlHelper. So what's different about #1? Do you mean that #1 could be something like `@Html.Menu()` and it would generate the full menu?

Comment: #1 means that it is like @Html.Menu() right. Your list items could be passed in to this method. The method generates the html and give it back to your view.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static helper method in your App_code folder.
Look at the section for [Reusing @helpers across multiple views](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

And you can take in a parameter for defining which LI should have the selected class.